# onkeydown dynamically added for textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi all I am having a textbox with onkeydown as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeydown="javascript:if (window.event.keyCode == 13 ) { window.event.keyCode = 9; } " ></asp:TextBox>
```

I would like to work it out for firefox with out writing a function is it possible. I know with the following function I can but I would like to know with out that can I do

```
function fnOnKeydown(evt) {
    var keycode = (window.event) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (keycode === 13) {

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: `javascript:` is useless in that context

Comment: `epascarello` removed `javascript:` but issue exists for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `javascript:` and you don't need to explicitly reference `event` as a property of `window`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 ) { event.keyCode = 9; } " ></asp:TextBox>
```

The function implicitly created for the event handler attribute will have `event` as its first parameter.

Comment: Well "all browsers" nowadays is a big promise, but to my knowledge it should. If you really want to write robust code you would separate your JavaScript from your markup however.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
arguments[0]
```

it should be an event
in your case it'll be this:

```
onclick="(function(){console.log(this, arguments);}).apply(this, arguments)"
```